# Video Miniport Driver On and Off using Hotkeys

Tags: windows, system, device, drivers

I am new to the Windows device drivers development world. I don't find anything related this topic.

I want to control Video miniport of windows 7/2008 by using hotkey. If I hit the hotkey for example Ctrl+s, the monitor is off, keyboard and mouse should diable(except my hotkey) and hit it again the same key monitor on( when the monitor on it goes to the lock screen), keybaord and mouse is enable.It should toggle every time if I hit the hotkey.

It works very similar to the win+L but the monitor turn on if you hit any key.But I want very specific key on the monitor, even Ctrl alt Delet should not on the monitor.The keyboard and mouse disable in this state.The main purpose I am doing this when the monitor is off/sleep mode it does not respond the ctrl alt dele events.I am disconnecting the monitor from ctrl alt dele even trigeer but monitor on and off using my hotkey only.

I know easy way to doing by autohotkey script to on and off monitor. But you can not stop
 interrupt generated by ctrl alt dele keys. For that I don't want to hack ctrl alt dele key instead I control the video miniport to toggle the monitor on and off using hotkey( any combination hotkey is fine but on and off monitor with same hotkey).

I am Linux device driver developer.I don't have experience on Windows device drives programming.Please guide me what are the possibilities and how complex it is(to successfully controlling video port through keyboard). I did research on MSDN site ... but I don't know where to start.
thank you in advance for help

Comment: Disabling the video card driver should just cause Windows to replace it with its generic VGA driver. Have you actually tried this from device manager to see if disabling it actually has the effect you want? Even you are able to blank the screen this way, it won't lock the computer. The keyboard and mouse will still work, and not just for CTRL-ALT-DEL, so it would be still be possible to enter commands, even click on things, you'd just be doing it blind.

Comment: Thanks for quick response 
Actually I will edit my question ... I want add above .. if the video port is disable/stop the keybord and mouse also disable except my hotkey.